# Returning javascript from controller without action specific js file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So the way that I've been taught initially to implement ajax in my rails apps is to create a js file for each action per controller, and then reference that js file within the respond_to block.

This is really annoying, and I like to include all my javascript in a single main.js file isntead of compartmentalizing every snippet.

This has been working nicely so far, except for when I want to pass an object to the proper function.

Here is how I'm supposed to handle the ajax request to create a new user listing in my app:

```
<%= form_for @client, action: :create, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :firstname, placeholder: 'First Name' %>
  <%= f.text_field :lastname, placeholder: 'Last Name' %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :status, value: true %>
  <%= submit_tag :create %>
<% end %>
```

.... form gets the remote: true tag.

```
 def create
   @client = current_trainer.clients.create(client_params)
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to clients_path }
     format.js 
   end
 end
```

.... create action passes response to default create file:

```
$('.active').prepend("<%= j render @client %>");
```

That's all fine and dandy. But I don't like this setup. I want to make a call like this instead:

```
 def create
  @client = current_trainer.clients.create(client_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to clients_path }
    format.js { render js: "theApp.clientsPage.saveClient();" }   
  end
 end
```

.... and then in the main.js.erb file I have:

```
    saveClient: function() {
        $('.active').prepend("<%= j render @client %>");
    },
```

BUT the error I'm getting is the following:

```
undefined method `render' for #<#<Class:0x007fd278f350c8>:0x007fd27b182298>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`main.js.erb` including only in layout I think, yes? Then it compiles on launch (for example this form on your `main#index` action) `index` action and you have no `@client`.

Just give an argument to `saveClient` function, like this:

```
saveClient: function( newElement ) {  
    $( ".active" ).prepend( newElement );  
},
```

And then in `create` action call:

```
format.js { render js: "theApp.clientsPage.saveClient( $( \"<div>#{ j render @client }</div>\" ) );" }
```

Comment: This is closer I think but no cigar. It literally appends the text '<%= j render @client %>' instead of the code that should evaluate.

Comment: @ninja08 sure, sorry. It's must be `#{...}` of course. And better append some block and not text, for example `div`.